# vue.js not all of the data is passed

Tags: vue.js, axios

Good evening, I am retrieving data with axios and when I console log it, I see that it has been retrieved successfully. When I pass that data to my component, the data is somehow not full. It just shows the data that was retrieved from first axios.get ( conversations but no messages ), but when I check it with vue.js debugging tools I can see that the object has ALL the data from server. Dont know where it goes wrong.

app.js

```
 const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        conversations: {
            list: [],
            current: {
                messages: []
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/conversations').then(response => {
            this.conversations.current = response.data[0];
        });

        axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
            this.conversations.current.messages = response.data;
            console.log(this.conversations.current);
            /* this console.log prints the json with 25 messages in it */
        });
    }
});
```

index.blade.php

```
<div class="list-group">
   <div class="list-group-item active">Messages</div>
   <chat-log :conversations="conversations"></chat-log>
</div>
```

chat-log.vue

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="chat-log pre-scrollable">
        <chat-message class="list-group-item" v-for="message in conversations.current.messages" :message="message"></chat-message>

        {{ conversations.current.messages }} // THIS IS EMPTY SOMEHOW
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['conversations']
    }
</script>
```

In chat-message component I created a method that is called on click to retrieve messages again and put them in array again and then they somehow appear but I dont understand why they do not appear on load.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe `axios.get('/messages')` finishes before `axios.get('/conversations')` , so when `axios.get('/conversations')` ends it replaces `axios.get('/messages')` data, maybe pull the `axios.get('/messages')` request inside `axios.get('/conversations').then()` method so it is called after `axios.get('/conversations')`

Comment: @Mohd_PH Thanks for the response. I've tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have no guarantee that those asynchronous calls will return in order unless used with a Promise:

```
Promise.all([
    axios.get('/conversations'),
    axios.get('/messages')
]).then(values => {
    this.conversations.current = values[0]
    this.conversations.current.messages = values[1]
})
```

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> Promise.all waits for all fulfillments (or the first rejection)

Also, your `data` property is not reactive. It must be declared as a function:

```
data () {
    return {
        conversations: {
            list: [],
            current: {
                messages: []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that your 'conversations' endpoint is going to resolve before the 'messages' endpoint. Try structuring it in a promise chain or, as @btl suggested, using `promise.all()`.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            conversations: {
                list: [],
                current: {
                    messages: []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        return Promise.all([
            axios.get('/conversations'),
            axios.get('/messages')
        ])
        .then(reply => {
            this.conversations.current = reply.data[0];
            this.conversations.current.messages = reply.data[1];
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay. Have you used the Chrome debugger? That would really come in handy here. You can set breakpoints inside your Vue code to see exactly what's happening when. Vue devtools are also good. They allow you to inspect your components and view internal scope. Give 'em a try.

Chrome Dev Tools:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Vue Dev Tools for Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en